# Poker terms in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

I am a native Spanish speaker that lives in the US. I don't get to practice often, but I do alright with my skills. But I'm not good at knowing words for specific hobbies/industries. I am working on a project where I need to know the Spanish terms for common poker things/situations. Can anyone provide insight into the following poker terms:

- Flush
- Straight
- Suited (not like the name of the suits, but like "I have two cards of the same suit" or "I have suited cards")
- Full House
- Jack (like the name of the card. I know there's "reyes" and "reinas" but I have no idea what you call a Jack)

**Please note** that I need the poker terms for these, not direct translations of the words. Like I know how to translate a "full house" literally but I doubt that's the actual poker term in Spanish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not agree with the other answers, specially with the gender. They seem literally taken from google translator. As a native speaker and player of Poker I can answer with this vocabulary from the basics of Poker:

> Cards: cartas
>
> Blinds: ciega
>
> Small Blind: ciega pequeña
>
> Big Blind: ciega grande
>
> Chips: fichas
>
> Pre-flop: it does not have translation, the same word is used as in english (pre-flop)
>
> Flop: same as in english (flop)
>
> River: river (same as in english)
>
> Raise: aumentar
>
> Fold: retirarse (big fail of other answers)
>
> Call: igualar
>
> Bet: apostar
>
> Limit Poker: póquer limitado
>
> Jackpot: bote
>
> Muck: cartas descartadas
>
> Pot Limit: limite del bote
>
> Pair: pareja
>
> **Jack: jota**
>
> Joker: jóquer
>
> **Full house: the same, full house**
>
> All-in: apostarlo todo
>
> Burn: quemar (action between river, flop, etc)
>
> 2 pair: doble pareja
>
> **Straight: escalera**
>
> **Flush: color**
>
> **Suited: cartas del mismo palo**

For more details, just answer or visit the following link:
https://www.pokerstars.es/poker/terms/

Comment: An alternative word for Joker is comodín.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comod%C3%ADn

Comment: Me agrada esta traduccion. Solo quiero agregar algunas alternativas coloquiales que usamos en Mexico:

Pair: (Un) par;

2 Pairs: Dos pares;

Straight: Corrida;

Three of a kind: Tercia

Answer (score 3):

At least in Spain

**Flush**: Color

**Straight**: Escalera

**Suited**: "Del mismo palo", literally "of the same suit".

**Full House**: Full

**Jack**: Jota (like the letter J). In the Spanish deck, it's called Sota though.

Comment: En español, **Jack** es el "comodín".

Answer (score 0):

Great list from [here](http://www.pocketfives.com/f7/poker-terms-spanish-20594/).

> - **Cards**: cartas
> - **Blinds**: a ciegas
> - **Small Blind**: el ciego pequeño
> - **Big Blind**: el ciego grande
> - **Chips**: fichas
> - **The Button**: el botón
> - **Pre-flop:** ronda inicial de apuestas (just say pre-flop though)
> - **Flop** = "flop" just use the english word for flop, turn, and river
> - **Raise:** aumentar
> - **Fold:** doblar
> - **Call:** ver
> - **Bet:** apostar

---

> - **Limit Poker:** póquer limitado
> - **NL Holdem:** holdem ilimitado
> - **Pot Limit:** limite de pozo
> - **2 pair:** dos pares
> - **straight:** escalera
> - **flush:** colores

Comment: Pot as «pozo» looks wrong to me. And «el ciego» with article, or «colores» in plural have a Google Translate feeling. I don't think the page is (linguistically) trustworthy.

Comment: @Ustanak If you have a problem with the mistakes then suggest corrections instead of calling out people. This is a community that strives for learning and tolerance. Perfect English in a Spanish language and usage forum is not necessary. Please refrain from such remarks in the future as they are not constructive criticism.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Same goes to you. Point out what the mistakes are in the future to improve the answer.

Comment: @Joze Thanks for answering, I will try in the future to comment to improve answers in the comments instead of the post to avoid misunderstandings

Answer (score 0):

While playing poker in Spain, the above applies, but you might use different shortened, general words to speed up play:

Again these are used while actually playing poker (in Spain, near Valencia) and not literal translations,

you can also reference these rules for some good terms:
https://www.campeonatopoker.es/reglas

Small Blind: pequeña

Big Blind: grande

Raise: you would just say "sube", pause per your playstyle, and then say the amount

Fold: "no", "no va" or "fold"

Call: call, veo, pago or igualo / igualar

Bet: you would just say "sube", pause per your playstyle, and then say the amount

Full house: you can just say "full" (pronounced like saying "fool" fast), or "fool house" if you think its needed to say all the words

All-in: same as in english "all in" (prounounced like "al-een")

2 pair: dobles

Pair: par

Flush: Color or colores

Suited: de color, or suited cards: cartas de color